# WAMPSERVER 3.1.3 32 bit, PHP 7.2.4 Oracle Client 11g issue

Tags: php, oracle, wampserver, oracleclient

I have installed Wampserver 3.1.3 32 bit on Windows 7 machine(32 bit). Wamp server has been installed correctly, getting a green icon on startup.

I have installed Oracle 32 client 11g on Windows machine and system environment variable path has been set `c:\app\USER\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;`, where `OCI.dll` resides.

For work with Oracle queries, I had enabled `extension=php_oci8_11g` in my `php.ini` file. Have verified, that `php_oci8_11g.dll` exists at `C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.2.4\ext`. And also verified, that `extension_dir` has been set to `extension_dir ="c:/wamp/bin/php/php7.2.4/ext/"` in my `php.ini`.

Whenever I start Wamp server, the icon changes to green, but errors are generated in `PHP_ERROR` log file

> [24-Apr-2018 18:10:07 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_11g' (tried: c:/wamp/bin/php/php7.2.4/ext/oci8_11g (The specified module could not be found.), c:/wamp/bin/php/php7.2.4/ext/php_oci8_11g.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Because of provided error my Oracle queries are not working.

Tried number of solution available but none of them have been worked so far. Had anyone faced the same issue? Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Apart from that when i installed WAMP server and check default php.ini , there is only  extension=oci8_12c present in php.ini there nothing like  extension=oci8_11g.......do php7.2.4 do not support oracle 11g ?

Comment: Then use the `oci8_12c` extension. It should be compatible with `oci8_11g`. I think 11g is not supported since php >= 7.x.

Comment: @DanielO Now error changes to "PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_12c' (tried: c:/wamp/bin/php/php7.2.4/ext/oci8_12c (The specified module could not be found.)", FYI, oracle client installed on my pc 11g

Comment: Then you should install the correct Oracle client for 12c `instantclient-basiclite-nt-12.2.0.1.0.zip` and the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable.

Comment: @DanielO Confirmed with DBA that correct oracle client has been installed (12c in this case), all VC version are up to date still not working !!!!!

Comment: I got it working after downloading correct dll files from below link 

https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/oci8/2.1.8/

php_oci8-2.1.8-7.2-ts-vc15-x86.zip